# Raspberry Pi's camera live stream/broadcast

Tags: html, web-server, streaming, raspberry-pi

I would like to stream Raspberry Pi's camera to my website. I want something like Twitch.tv, so a one way live stream. The webserver is on the Raspberry. I've never done something like this so i'm looking for simple solutions. I've tried streaming with VLC but the 2 sec delay is too much for me. WebRTC seems too complicated. Node.js maybe?

Thanks for the help!